# how to support Promises in Internet Explorer 11 using laravel mix?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-mix

I'm trying to figure out how to get `laravel-mix` to convert ES6 javascript code into javascript code Internet Explorer 11 can use.

I've setup a brand new laravel 9 project and made the following changes:

`resources/js/app.js`

```js
let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000);
});

promise.then(
  result => alert(result),
);
```

Added to `package.json`

```json
"browserslist": [
    "IE 11"
]
```

Added to `resources/views/welcome.blade.php`

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Finally

```sh
npm install
npx mix
php artisan serve
```

Code runs fine in Chromium but fails in Internet Explorer with error `'Promise' is undefined`.
How do I get laravel-mix to include a Promise polyfill?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill

Comment: @KarlHill Tried that without success, maybe the mix config needs to be updated?

Comment: @8ctopus You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-mix-polyfill to polyfill the Promise implementation for IE11.

Comment: If you don't mind skipping integration with laravel-mix, you can just add `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>` in the blade view/layout. Otherwise, you can try adding `window.Promise = require('promise-polyfill').default;` in `resources/js/bootstrap.js` (untested)

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thank you, that did the trick! Feel free to answer the question in order to get the bounty.

Comment: @YohanesGultom Thank you for your suggestion, I prefer to pack everything using laravel mix so Oluwafemi's solution is better.

Comment: FYI https://death-to-ie11.com

Comment: Everyone agrees that it should have been killed a long time ago, unfortunately still see people using it.

Comment: unfortunately some clients still requires IE11. I was recommending to our company to kill the support but I get this "Corporate America" usage statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a mix extension such as `laravel-mix-polyfill`

```js
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

require('laravel-mix-polyfill');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .polyfill({
      enabled: true,
      useBuiltIns: "usage",
      targets: "firefox 50, IE 11"
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind skipping integration with laravel-mix, you can just add this in the blade view/layout:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@8/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

Otherwise, you can try adding in `resources/js/bootstrap.js` (untested):

```
window.Promise = require('promise-polyfill').default;
```